# Объединение меток хостинг

Tags: предложение, метки

Предлагаю объединить метки: [хостинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) и [hosting](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/hosting)

Comment: ...или сжечь обе.

Comment: @D-side сжигание не эффективно.

Comment: @alexolut не принципиально, как именно. На крайний случай есть чёрный список, который точно эффективен. Вопрос, крайний ли это случай.